# Insert list of images as a column in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, image, list, datagrid

I have made few lists and it looks like this:

```
public class MyDataObject
{
    public double AmountNeed { get; set; }
    public double TotalLose { get; set; }
    public double TotalGain { get; set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; set; }
}
```

after few calculations i insert them in a `dataGrid`:

```
var L = new List<MyDataObject>();
for (int z = 0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
    {

       var d = new MyDataObject();

       d.AmountNeed = Math.Ceiling((goalexp - currentexp) / (list_Exp[z]));
       d.TotalLose = d.AmountNeed * (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]);
       d.TotalGain = d.AmountNeed * list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z];
       d.TotalCost = d.TotalGain - d.TotalLose;

       L.Add(d);

    }

dataGrid.ItemsSource = L;
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Click="button_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="40" Margin="155,10,247,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Margin="0,10,77,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,85,10,10" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:Converter x:Key="conv" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                                <Binding Path="." />
                                <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, I would like to make another list, something like `d.images` where i can add to it images inside the `for` loop and then add it to the `dataGrid` just like the rest of the columns.

Eventually, i try to have 5 columns where 4 of them are `double` and one contains images.

Thank You.

Comment: I would hardly recommend to get familiar with MVVM. You can achive this very easily when using MVVM and a TemplateColumn for your image.

Comment: The thing is i dont want it to be same images. I have for example few buttons. Every button should populate a different list of images in the dataGrid, unless i didnt understand you mate.

Comment: Showing different images is not the problem. I just wanted to say that this is really easy when using the MVVM pattern and pain in the ass when trying to do it via code behind ;) And your code looks like you aren't using MVVM.

Comment: So each MyDataObject/row in the DataGrid will contain a single Image?

Comment: Hey mate, yes. the column length of image list will be same as the other and in each row there will be an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add an `Uri` property to your `MyDataObject` class that contains the path to the image:

```
public class MyDataObject
{
    public double AmountNeed { get; set; }
    public double TotalLose { get; set; }
    public double TotalGain { get; set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

You could then add a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with an `Image` element that binds this property:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,85,10,10" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:Converter x:Key="conv" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                        <Binding Path="." />
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="AmountNeed" Binding="{Binding AmountNeed}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TotalLose" Binding="{Binding TotalLose}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TotalGain" Binding="{Binding TotalGain}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TotalCost" Binding="{Binding TotalCost}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
for (int z = 0; z<list_Exp.Count; z++)
{

    var d = new MyDataObject();

    d.AmountNeed = Math.Ceiling((goalexp - currentexp) / (list_Exp[z]));
    d.TotalLose = d.AmountNeed* (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]);
    d.TotalGain = d.AmountNeed* list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z];
    d.TotalCost = d.TotalGain - d.TotalLose;
    d.ImageSource = new Uri(@"c:\test\pic.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    L.Add(d);
}
```

Comment: and how can i do it if in each row there should be a different image? also i have updated the question with the current XAML. because now it contains another bind and im not sure how to combine between them.

Comment: Set the ImageSource property of each MyDataObject to a different path in your for loop?

Comment: I included sample markup in my answer. Take a look at this.

Comment: dude you are the best

Comment: only thing is that when i try to combine it with data that were binded into the dataGrid before, it gets deleted and shows only the data from `MyDataObject`. From my understanding it cancels the bind from `SampleDataSource` once code executed.

Comment: I don't understand. But please ask a new question if you have another issue. And please make sure to include all relevant parts of your code including the Converter class. It's unclear what it does.